# Comparing dates in MySQL ignoring time portion of a DateTime field

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, date-comparison

I need to compare dates in MySQL ignoring the time portion in a `DateTime` column. I have tried the following SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM order_table where order_date=date_format('2012-05-03', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

It doesn't retrieve any row even though there is a date `2012-05-03 10:16:46` in MySQL table. How can the time portion in the `DateTime` field be ignored while comparing dates in MySQL?

Comment: what is the data type of order_date?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You could use the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM order_table
WHERE date(order_date) = '2012-05-03'
```

But this is more efficient, if your table is large and you have an index on `order date`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM order_table
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-03'
AND order_date < '2012-05-04'
```

Comment: How about `WHERE order_date LIKE '2012-05-03%'` which one's faster?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to pass in a date then you can try something like this:

```
where YEAR(order_date)='2012' AND MONTH(order_date)='05' AND DAY(order_date)='03'
```

You can look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more functions.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM order_table WHERE date(order_date) = '2012-05-03';
```

Comment: this cannot use index on `order_date`

Answer (score 6):

@Mark has got the good approach but just be careful that you will always have to calculate and find next day in that case. If you want to avoid that and still ignore time you could do following:

```
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-27 00:00:00' AND order_date <= '2012-05-27 23:59:59'
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you can use function like [`date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date). But in this case speed can be decreased, because index cannot be using. So, I recommend to use

```
SELECT * FROM order_table 
WHERE order_date between('2012-05-03 0:0:0' and '2012-05-03 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is bit old .... but a correct answer also is using the date_format at the column order_date like below:

```
SELECT * FROM order_table where date_format(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d')='2012-05-03';
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the following could be used when comparing dates in MySQL:

```
DATEDIFF() Subtract two dates
TIMEDIFF() Subtract time
TIMESTAMPDIFF() Subtract an interval from a datetime expression
PERIOD_DIFF()   Return the number of months between periods
```

for more on date functions MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had , `DATE_FORMAT` and `CONVERT_TZ`

The only one worked for me is this

```
DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`order_item`.created, '+0:00', '+2:00'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') 

BETWEEN 
('12/02/2018 01:42') 
AND 
('12/02/2018 10:51')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it something like that, if you want to keep formatting as it is.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as order_date from order_table  
    where DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '18/04/2023'
```

or

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as order_date from order_table  
        where DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y') between '18/04/2023' and 
        '20/04/2023'
```

for example.