# MySQL retrieve results between 2 dates without time factor doesn't output results of exact date

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776539/comparing-dates-in-mysql-ignoring-time-portion-of-a-datetime-field) gives us the answer on how to query between 2 dates without using time factor and it is like this

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM order_table
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-03'
AND order_date < '2012-05-04'
```

If we have the following dates

1. 2012-05-02
2. 2012-05-04

And we use this

```
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-01'
AND order_date < '2012-05-04'
```

It will only output `2012-05-02` and **it will not output** `2012-05-04`

**Question:** How can I include `2012-05-04` in my result? I don't want my user to choose `2012-05-05` just to output `2012-05-04`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-01'
AND order_date < '2012-05-05'
```

A day has duration of 24 hours, but this can be measured in extremely small units, so 23:59:59 is NOT the final point of the duration. MySQL now does support fractions of seconds so please do not rely on 23:59:59 see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html

The one and only **always accurate** method is to use LESS THAN THE NEXT DAY.

If you don't want your user to see that next day value simply take the chosen end date but add 1 day to that in your code.  e.g.

```
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-01'
AND order_date < date_add('2012-05-04',INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: SQL doesn't have fractional seconds in its times, so `23:59:59` **is** the final point of the duration.

Comment: Incorrect, but it is also simply an unsafe assimption, particularly as there is a workable safe alternative.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that recent change.

Comment: Oh, I'll remove the downvote. I didn't know about that change also. Sorry.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for saving me. 1 second error is still an error.

Comment: Thank you, providing you with a safe method for filtering a date range is done with great pleasure I assure you. Please advocate it for others who haven't yet seen the light. Note the approach works in all sql dialects but the date arithmetic detail may change. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<` to `<=`, because `<` means that it doesn't include dates that match that date

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM order_table
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-01'
AND order_date <= '2012-05-04'
```

You can also use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM order_table
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2012-05-04'
```

This assumes that the datatype of `order_date` is `DATE`, not `DATETIME`. If it's `DATETIME`, you need to ensure that the time part is `00:00:00`, because that's the default time used when you convert a `DATE` to a `DATETIME`. Or you can include an explicit `23:59:59.999999` in the end time in your query, as in Cary Bondoc's answer.

Comment: Yeah, confirmed. Your code will work if the case is `DATE`, **not** `DATETIME`. +1!

Comment: MySQL 5.7 supports microseconds, so by assuming 23:59:59 is the finite end point you are building potential bugs into queries, and that is completely avoidable by using less than `the next day `.  Furthermore using less than the next day technique applies in any rdbms that has precision finer than 1 second.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Even though it supports it, you don't get them by default, you have to explicitly give a precision to the `DATETIME` datatype to get fractions.

Comment: And if such a change is applied to columns the bugs will emerge. The very worst aspect of the 23:59:59 assumption us that it produces a 1 second gap and hence some transactions may be completely missed in reports etc. The one and only safe way to do date/time ranges is to use less than the next day. Between does not work either because it uses = on both the lower and upper boundaries.

Comment: Since he seems to be taking the date range from user input, you should show how to apply your "next day" solution when you're given the end date as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Add a fix time to your query

```
order_date >= '2012-05-03 00:00:00' AND order_date <= '2012-05-04 23:59:59'
```

2012-05-03 **00:00:00** means that we want to start the search on the start of `2012-05-03`

2012-05-04 **23:59:59** means that we want to end the search at the end of day of `2012-05-04`

So your query would be like this

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM order_table
WHERE order_date >= '2012-05-03 00:00:00'
AND order_date <= '2012-05-04 23:59:59'
```

Comment: You need to use `<=`, not `<`. Otherwise it won't match when `order_date = 2012-05-04 23:59:59`